# use regex string from a file to do a search in another file

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, command

I want to grep something in fileA by using regex stringA. Since this stringA is too long (some ids), so I put them into a file with | delimited. for example,

12345|34567|98765|78657

Now how to do the grep without copying the regex string from stringA file. It is impossible since there are almost 40k.

cat fileA | egrep stringA.file > thisIdsStuff

Thanks

Comment: As a general piece of advice, I would avoid thinking of things as "impossible," especially if your question shows that you don't know whether there is a way to achieve it or not. Only in open problems (such as the Halting Problem) is impossibility a feasible option... and even then, what's true is it hasn't been done *yet*.

Comment: accept this advice. I agree. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `egrep -f your_regex.file file_to_be_search > search.result`

> In man **egrep**
>
> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)